# adding additional javascript after postback on updatePanel

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Im using updatePanel and after postback which updates it I would like to add some javascript to the page which would execut after all javascript run which is specified on

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(MyJSFunc);
```

Thanks for any hint how to do that

Comment: Add the JS `<script>` block to the update panel code in VB/C#?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function(){
    MyJSFunc.apply(this, arguments);
    MyJSFuncAfterEndRequestFunc.apply(this, arguments);
});
```

Comment: I dont really understad. Im using server siode methods to get set of point which after updatePanel is updated are shown on the google map on my site. Im using javascript to add markers to google map but want to generate that set of points on server side and then pass it to the site

Comment: So you could output the set of points as a `json` object, or in a hidden field, or as `data-` attributes, etc. Then `MyJSFuncAfterEndRequestFunc` would pick it up and process.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock.aspx). With this you can add in javascript to your page after the postback.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question the other day, [Execute JQuery after ASP.Net Microsoft AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254769/execute-jquery-after-asp-net-microsoft-ajax)

I think the answer provided by trelston is what you are looking for.